# What Does $P(|Z|>a)$ Mean?

Tags: probability

If $Z$ is a standard random variable with $Z\sim N(0,1)$, what does $P(|Z|>a)$ where $a$ is a given constant mean? Is it equivalent to the following?(Note that $\sigma=1$ and $\mu=0$)
$$
P(|\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}|>a)=1-P(|X|\leq a)=1-P(-a\le X\le a)\\=1-(P(X\le a)-P(X\le-a))=1-(F(a)-F(-a))\tag{1}
$$
And supposing that $F$ and $f$ are distribution and density functions of $X$ respectively:
$$
F(a)-F(-a)=\int_{-\infty}^{a}f(t)dt-\int_{-\infty}^{-a}f(t)dt
$$

Comment: Looks like you have the right idea (I am assuming you meant $Z$ in place of $X$); no need to introduce $\mu$ and $\sigma$ if it is standard normal.  Also worth noting that for a standard normal, the CDF satisfies $F(-a)=1-F(a)$ by symmetry

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Prob+%7C+Z+%7C+%3E+a%2C+Z%7Estandard+normal+distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *any* random variable $X$:

$$P(|X|>a)=P(X<-a)+P(X>a)$$

Now, if $P(X=a)=0$ (as it is for all continuous random variables), then

$$P(X\ge a)=P(X=a)+P(X>a)=P(X>a)$$

so we can substitute above:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}P(|X|>a)&=&P(X<-a)+P(X\ge a)\\&=&P(X<-a)+1-P(X<a)\\&=&1-(F_X(a)-F_X(-a))\end{array}$$

where $F_X$ is c.d.f. of $X$ (recall the definition of c.d.f: $F_X(a):=P(X<a)$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$). So, your statement is correct not only for the normal distribution but for any continuous distribution.